# gcc - pedantic wont compile, ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code How to fix this?

Tags: c, gcc

I need that code for my program to have colors. But it wont compile if i use -pedantic. Is there a way around this? its  btw

```
gcc -pedantic MP1.c -o hahah
MP1.c: In function `main':
MP1.c:65: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
MP1.c:686:30: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
```

line 65:

```
int originalAttrs = ConsoleInfo.wAttributes;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move declaration of `originalAttrs` to the top of the scope in which it is used. The error is unrelated to use of `ConsoleInfo.wAttributes` but to the location of the declaration of `originalAttrs`. Without seeing the entire code, it is probably something like:

```
printf("hello\n"); /* For example. */
int originalAttrs = ConsoleInfo.wAttributes;
```

To fix:

```
int originalAttrs;
printf("hello\n"); /* For example. */
originalAttrs = ConsoleInfo.wAttributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either fix the code so it complies with the C90 standard (as [hmjd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915124/827263) suggests), or tell gcc to use a newer version of the standard.

C does permit mixed declarations and statements starting with the C99 standard.

If you use

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic
```

or

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic
```

it should work.